# Spring MVC (5.0.8) with Spring Security (5.0.7) Basic Authentication not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to enable Spring Security in my Spring MVC application which serves some REST web services (Java 8). The problem I have is whatever I do the auth just doesn't work at all. I can access my REST endpoints without any credentials. I use this manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Git repo with full code of my app is here: https://github.com/SP8EBC/MKS_JG_ONLINE

SecurityConfig.java looks as follows

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()                 
            .withUser(Secret.user).password("{noop}" + Secret.password).roles("USER");       
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//         http
//           .csrf()
//               .disable()
//           .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
//               .anyRequest().authenticated()
//           .and()
//           .httpBasic()
//               .realmName("test")
//               .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"pl.jeleniagora.mks.dao.repository"})
@ComponentScan("pl.jeleniagora.mks")
public class AppConfig{
// beans and app config
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MKS_JG_ONLINE</display-name>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>pl.jeleniagora.mks.ws.config</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>pl.jeleniagora.mks.ws.controllers</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file />
   </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

When I start the Tomcat 8.5 in debug mode I see that the SecurityConfig loads (execution stops at breakpoint in configure and configureGlobal). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the spring security filter configured in your `web.xml`. This filter is needed to apply security. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security requires, next to the security configuration, a servlet filter to be registered.

Add the following to your `web.xml` (explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml)).

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will add the filter and will be applied to all requests.

However as you are using a recent servlet container I would suggest to ditch the `web.xml` and create 2 java classes to do the bootstrapping. (See also [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc)).

First bootstrap your application

```
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebConfig.class }; // or whatever it is called or return `null`
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }
}
```

Then add the one that bootstraps/configures Spring Security filter

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
```

Now everything is configured in Java and you can do without your `web.xml`.